# How can I call a Method of a Content from MasterPage in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to call a method of a Content from a master page sending a Parameter to manipulate one label.

```
public partial class MasterCategoria : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnSalada_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        produtosCategoria x = new produtosCategoria();
        x.changeLabel("Salada");
    }
}
```

Manipulating this button on this WebForm which is a Content

```
public partial class produtosCategoria : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void changeLabel(string name)
    {
        lblTexto.Text = name;
    }
```

But this isn't working. How can I do this work?

Thank you guys, and sorry about my english.

Answer (score 1):

The object of type `produtosCategoria` is already created and it can be accessed from your master page via `this.Page`.

So to change the label of your content page you can do as in the snippet below.

Also, I added a simple type check so you won't get an error if another content page is loaded

```
protected void btnSalada_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if it is the correct content page
    if (this.Page.GetType() == typeof(produtosCategoria)) 
    {
        produtosCategoria x = (produtosCategoria)this.Page;
        x.changeLabel("Salada");
    }
}
```

Note: When code executes in the master page `this` is the master page and `this.Page` is the content page